# AS: Rotation of ImageView around a position

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, rotation

I want to rotate one imageView around one fix position and not around it´s own axis. How could i manage this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="90"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="1000"
android:startOffset="0">
</rotate>

Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
a.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the pivotX and pivotY values to specify the point around which you want to rotate the image.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:-** 
*It will help you in your rotation task*

```
  <rotate
  android:duration="2000"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:toDegrees="360" >
  </rotate>

</set>

 Animation sampleFadeAnimation =     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PreviewImageActivity.this,R.anim.rotate);
sampleFadeAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
    yourImageView.startAnimation(sampleFadeAnimation);
```

Comment: And now it works, now i want to rotate the image around a specific coordinate. At the moment the imageview rotates around axis itself.

Comment: The imageView, which rotates around a specific coordinate should not rotate around it´s own axis. My aim is to let the imageView rotates up the edges of the screenWidth in an infinite amount of times. Anyways, the repeatCount doesn´t work.

Comment: I am going to share a link with you where you can study about the rotation and scaling of objects and their respective transformations.You will get a good idea of it and will also clear your doubts.

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=--VQBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=how+to+rotate+an+object+at+specific+coordinate+in+xml&source=bl&ots=UmH6H27XP1&sig=xtkGSWTKbAPmHXIwtkt7O2Dkj84&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji_p2pyfDYAhXHvY8KHZK_DdAQ6AEwA3oECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20rotate%20an%20object%20at%20specific%20coordinate%20in%20xml&f=false

Comment: Try this link.Even if you have further doubts ,you can still clarify by replying to my comment .Thank you.

Comment: OK one question: Is there a command which allows the animation to begin immediatly the new animation when the last animation is finished? In other words now my animation rotates infinite but when the first animation is over, there is a little delay and after this delay there comes the next rotate animation. is it possible to make the infinite animation smooth with no delay?

Comment: @Chralt can I share CSS animation information with you.It might be what you are looking for.If not I will try to find this answer later.

Comment: Yeah please help me with my issue! :)

Comment: i can mainly describe what i want: 1. place an image right in the center of an frame layout (the frame layout is the bottom half screen of the full screen) 2. rotate a second image right around the first image in an ellipse shape 3. the maximal x.size of the ellipse is the screenwidth. the maximal y.size of the ellipse is the quarter screenheight. Understandable?